# Why async function is not waiting for completion?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll, v3.0.0.0 and I'm trying to create an object type of  CookieAuthenticationProvider using this code:

```
var provider= new  CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnResponseSignIn =  async  context  =>
        {
            var claims=await GetClaims(identity.Name); //I get the claims here.
            context.Identity.AddClaims(clais); //The claims are being added.
        }
}
```

After this is executed I get an error saying **"An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."**

The method GetClaims() looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaims(String test)
    {
      .....var claims=await GetInfo(test);

      return claims;
    }
```

**If I remove the async from the OnResponseSignIn and make GetClaims() synchronous everything works.**

What am I doing wrong? If I want to make OnResponseSignIn async and the GetClaims() awaitable, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Your problem is because `OnResponseSignIn` isn't intended to be `async`. It's type is `Action<T>`. So, when you use an `async` lambda, it's becoming an `async void` method, and that's what's causing your problems. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: thanks for the help this totally clear my doubt I will mark this as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you retrieve claims but as per my experience with async I would do something like this.

```
 private Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims(string name)
        {
            // Get your claim here.
        }
```

In configureAuth I would do

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Func<CookieResponseSignInContext, Task> asyncFunc = async ctx =>
            {
                var claims = await GetClaims(ctx.Identity.Name);
                ctx.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
            };

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                       regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                    OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                    {
                        asyncFunc(context);
                    }
                }
            });
           .....
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it asynchronous, it doesn't make sense for my scenario to do the work asynchronously. Stephen Cleary answered my doubt.